# Does Stack Overflow use an ORM?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the architecture details of Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow)

Does Stack Overflow use an ORM? If yes, which one?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/is-stackoverflow-still-using-linq-to-sql-as-the-orm

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow

Comment: even more specific: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow uses Linq-To-SQL as its ORM.  This [has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow).