# How do you use LINQ to SQL at stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture, scalability

according to this [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/is-stackoverflow-still-using-linq-to-sql-as-the-orm) question, SO is still using LINQ to SQL. We use it as well at our shop, but i've had some problems with it. I'm very interested in knowing how you guys use it? Do you use it for reading only or do you do both reads and writes? Anything in particular you've done to make it scale? Maybe any of the members of the team could write a detail blog post (and link to this question) about it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

We use it when performance is not critical for both reads and writes.

When stuff is performance sensitive or requires full-text queries, we hand code the SQL.

Comment: I have 2 questions : 1) since your team using dapper, why there is still a need for linq to sql? 2) do you use stored procedure? Or inline SQL? Why your team choose the one over the other?