# What ORM does Stack Overflow use with their ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: discussion

What [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) does Stack Overflow use with their [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Mar 2011, they are using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Here's the [introduction post for Dapper](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) by the developer Sam.

Below is the original accepted answer which is out of date.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

This will go into more detail concerning the stack that StackOverflow uses (including it's ORM).

Comment: Who the heck is this "Sam" person? :)

Comment: Looks like they use both entity framework core and dapper now days. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316278/the-road-to-net-core-please-help-stack-exchange-test-ef-core

Answer (score 8):

They are actually using [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and they have open-sourced it.

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)

Comment: [Nope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJP1DphOWPs&feature=youtube_gdata_player) - Not anymore