# Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, outage

Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance but it's not reported [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/)

---

Update: The outage affected Meta as well as other sites, but fortunately it was quickly solved.

---

Another update:

[image: Web Applications is offline for maintenance]

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: It works for me ...

Comment: This isn't applicable for a single site s all the sites were down for a few minutes. But they were restored back very quick. Not off-topic. Leaving open.

Comment: @NogShine As far as I could tell, only SO is down, while all other sites are up.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog [Interpersonal SE is still down](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions)

Comment: @scohe001 That's an error page URL. The site works for me.

Comment: I can confirm Interpersonal seems to be back up now too ;)

Comment: @Laurel D'oh! I'm sitting here refreshing an error link. That about sums up my week. Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: @scohe001 see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1047917377516687360):

> We're investigating a database overload and working to resolve it ASAP.

Screenshot from Twitter page

> [image: From Twitter]

Comment: I found this 11s after it was posted :)