# Generic site icon and theme in "We are Offline" page

Tags: bug, design, offline

I noticed that some pages look like a generic beta page when they are down:

> [image: Skeptics]
>
> [image: ELL]
>
> [image: MSE]
>
> [image: ELU meta]

I think all these pages are supposed to have their icon/background color/font because this is what ELU looked like:

> [image: English Language & Usage]

Is this a bug?

Comment: It might depend on when the server determines if the site is offline. One is a legitimate "offline" message and one sometimes appears as a "I couldn't do anything so I'm just gonna display this offline message instead". While I was refreshing a particular site during the outage, it switched back and forth between the generic and site-specific offline message depending on how long it took to load.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316331/289691